# Как получить индекс элемента в listbox, на котором фокус?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть список, каждый элемент содержит текст и кнопку, [вот пример](https://ibb.co/mE1pw7), таких элементов может быть много. Понятно, что одинаковые кнопки одинаковы по имени и именно по имени не различимы. При нажатии на кнопку элемент не выбирается, а просто фокусится. Как при нажатии на кнопку получить индекс этого элемента?

Comment: Просто привяжите выделение элемента к bool свойству. То есть к примеру имеем `ObservableCollection<MyVM> SuperList` - внутри MyVM имеем `public bool IsSelected {get; set;}` ну и к ней привязка. Тогда дальше уже можно без проблем узнать и индекс и объект и все остальное...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я имею ввиду не выбранный элемент, а тот, на который наведена мышь.

Comment: А какой смысл в получение элемента, на котором сейчас мышь? Это не правильный подход как по мне. Вы уверены, что правильно пытаетесь решить задачу? Какова конечная цель, для чего это все?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Смысл в том, что при нажатии на кнопку элемент только фокусится, а не выбирается. Не нажимать же мне на элемент, а потом на кнопку, это как-то криво совсем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как бы реализовал это я...

### XAML разметка:

Тут самая простая разметка, где задается стиль внутреннего содержимого ListBoxItem, а также привязывается IsSelected.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Content="Select" Command="{Binding Command}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

### Код:

Тут тоже все просто. По сути создаем свойство IsSelected и командой меняем, но кто знает, может для вас это в новинку... Да и повторение не помешает..

1. Создаем вспомогательные классы, которые реализуют INPC и ICommand:

   ```
   public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }

   public class RelayCommand : ICommand
   {
       private readonly Action<object> execute;
       private readonly Func<object, bool> canExecute;

       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
       {
           add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
           remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
       }

       public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
       {
           this.execute = execute;
           this.canExecute = canExecute;
       }

       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
       {
           return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
       }

       public void Execute(object parameter)
       {
           execute(parameter);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Далее нам понадобится реализовать "внутренности" для нашего итема:
   *Тут мы создаем свойства имени, выделения и команды, команду привязываем к методу `SelectItem()`, ну и реализовываем для обновления интерфейса INPC (хотя он тут нужен только для IsSelected, остальное в моем примере статично).*

   ```
   public class ItemViewModel : VM
   {
       public ItemViewModel(string name)
       {
           Name = name;
           Command = new RelayCommand(_ => SelectItem());
       }

       void SelectItem()
       {
           IsSelected = true;
       }

       private string _name;
       public string Name
       {
           get => _name;
           set
           {
               _name = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       private bool _isSelected;
       public bool IsSelected
       {
           get => _isSelected;
           set
           {
               _isSelected = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       public ICommand Command { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Создаем коллекцию, которая будет содержать в себе все и в итоге к которой мы привяжемся через Binding в View:
   *Привязываемся к свойствам, помним это, а для того, что бы наш интерфейс обновлял данные при добавление/удаление из коллекции - используем ObservableCollection (она "из коробки" имеет все необходимое).*

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
   ```
4. Ну что, осталось задать DataContext и заполнить какими нибудь данными:
   *Я прям в MainWindow укажу все это дело, но по хорошему стоит использовать свою VM.*

   ```
   DataContext = this;
   Items.Add(new ItemViewModel("Привет"));
   Items.Add(new ItemViewModel("Чудесный"));
   Items.Add(new ItemViewModel("Мир!"));
   ```

Что бы нам получить выделенный элемент - можем воспользоваться LINQ:

```
var item = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected);
```

Вот и все, результатом будет что то вроде этого:

[image: Result]

Есть еше вариант в привязке SelectedItem` у ListBox, тогда можно вынести команду за пределы ItemViewModel, переписать ее на получение объекта, что то вроде:

```
public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { get; set; }
void SelectItem(object vm)
{
    if (vm != null)
        SelectedItem = vm as ItemViewModel;
}
```

В View тогда параметром передаем нужные данные:

```
<Button Content="Select" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

В общем, дерзайте и удачи в изучение WPF!

Answer (score 0):

В конечном итоге нашел решение, как получить индекс элемента с кнопкой в пару строк.

```
        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            Grid grid = (Grid)button.Parent;
            //Отсюда можно вытащить объект, закрепленный за элементом списка
            Object object = grid.DataContext;
            //А отсюда сам индекс
            int index = List.Items.IndexOf(object);
        }
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что это неверное решение? Это приемлемо для WinForms, но не для WPF. Как по мне, писать приложение изначально надо правильно. Но дело ваше...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Почему оно не верное? Что в нем неправильного?

Comment: WPF без MVVM паттерна - это как велосипед без колес, вроде подвинуть как то можно, но не на всю свою мощь. А по правилам MVVM все должно быть четко разделено на 3 слоя Model ViewModel и View. Так вот из кода (будь то ViewModel или Model) вы не как не должны знать, что во View (дизайн) у вас есть ListBox c именем List. По правилам MVVM вы должны писать код так, будто у вас вовсе нет дизайна, а есть просто объекты (коллекции, свойства, классы) с которыми вы взаимодействуете.

Comment: Посмотрите на мой ответ, знаю ли я из c# кода, что у меня есть ListBox в Xaml разметке? Нет. Знает только сам дизайн по средствам binding то, что есть некая команда `Command` и некая коллекция `Items`. Вот так должно быть и у вас. Ну а если вы пишите так, как в своем ответе, то какой смысл в использование WPF? Использовали бы дальше WinForms, там такая логика работы с объектами приемлема.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я и не говорю, что ваш вариант ответа не верен. В wpf я не так сильно разбираюсь и использую его для настройки интерфейса под себя. Возможно, мне стоило поступить, как посоветовали вы, но тогда мне слишком много пришлось бы переписывать, на что у меня, пока что, нет времени.

Comment: Смотрите как бы дальше не пришлось бы много костылей делать.  Моя задача сказать как правильно можно решить ту или иную задачу. Принять это или нет - ваше дело.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ За что я вам очень благодарен, впредь буду стараться делать по MVVM.