# Не работает передача параметров через команды WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-commands

При просмотре в отладке даже не вызывается команда. Сделано все по образцу, где ошибка никак не могу понять

> RelayCommand

```
 public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
  {
 private Action<T> action;
 public RelayCommand(Action<T> action) => this.action = action;
 public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
 #pragma warning disable CS0067
 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
 #pragma warning restore CS0067
 public void Execute(object parameter) => action((T)parameter);
  }
```

> MainViewModel

```
public static ObservableCollection<NewArticlesViewModel> articles_list { get;set; }
public MainViewModel()
{

articles_list = new ObservableCollection<NewArticlesViewModel>();
LoadData();
 }
public ObservableCollection<NewArticlesViewModel> Articles_list
{
get { return articles_list; }
set
{
    articles_list = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Articles_list");
}
}
private void LoadData()
{
Articles_list = b.GetArticles();
 }
```

> viewmodel

```
public ICommand RenameCommand { get; set; }
public NewArticlesViewModel (int id, string name, string category,string 
authorname, string text,string url, int authorid, string description, 
DateTime creationdate)

 {
this.Id = id;
this.Name = name;
this.Category = category;
this.Text = text;
this.AuthorId = authorid;
this.Description = description;
this.CreationDate = creationdate;
this.Url = url;
this.AuthorName = authorname;
RenameCommand = new RelayCommand<NewArticlesViewModel>(Rename);
 }
private void Rename(NewArticlesViewModel article)
{
NewArticels.CurrentArticle = article;
}
```

> View

```
<ListBox   Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles_list}" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="550" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="616"  >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="739" Height="520" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="151" Height="221" Margin="20 30 20 20">
                   
                            <Button  Command="{Binding RenameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                        

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Код где? Я вижу `ShowNews = new MyCommands(ShowDetailNews);`, ок, а где остальное? Где `ShowNews`? Также и кнопка, вы несколько вопросов подряд про `ListBox` спрашиваете, а тут просто кнопка, где она у вас? Внутри `ListBox`? И что за странная реализация команды? Где вы вообще передаете параметры? И да, хватит уже игнорировать метку C#...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ отредактировано. Да, кнопка в listbox. Подозреваю, что проблема в самом классе MyCommands, потому что я не могу получить параметры в самой реализации команды, но не совсем понимаю, где

Comment: `Да, кнопка в listbox` - тогда почему у вас команда в главном VM, где предположу, у вас сама коллекция с объектами? Ну и также, как я сказал выше, где в вашей команде передача параметров? Ну то есть обычно, параметры команды передаются так `SomeCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(arg => SomeMethod(arg));` и далее `void SomeMethod(string arg){ //Делаем что-то с arg }`, где у вас это?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  прописав SomeCommand = new MyCommands<string>(arg => SomeMethod(arg));  оно светит ошибку. Подозреваю, для того, чтобы не светило, надо что-то изменить сам класс MyCommands. Не могли бы вы подсказать что именно, пожалуйста?

Comment: Конечно будет ошибка) У вас весьма странная реализация `ICommand`) Поищите любую другую, удобную для вас реализацию. Например, можете взять [как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553), самая минимальная, лишь выполнение, без `CanExecute`, можете взять [от сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824250/220553) - параметры передаются через лямбду как `object`, в методе надо будет преобразовать в нужный тип. Реализаций полно, можете сами погуглить по запросу `wpf icommand implementation`, либо написать свою реализацию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282902/373567

Comment: Вопрос в порядок приведите, ни единого пробела, все в одну кашу... Вам самим приятно это читать? Также почему `public static ObservableCollection<NewArticlesViewModel> articles_list { get;set; }`? Это должно быть приватным полем, которое вообще не используется где либо, лишь в свойстве. Ну и как вы поняли, что "не работает"? Точку остановки на строке `NewArticels.CurrentArticle = article;` ставили? При нажатии на кнопку попадает туда?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не попадает в отладке туда

Comment: Делайте тогда минимальный, самодостаточный пример, чтобы мы могли воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Я вон даже [проверил ваш код](https://i.imgur.com/qOjIeLW.gif), скопировал ваш [c#](https://pastebin.com/titPw6PV) (убрав лишнее для простоты), скопировал прям целиком ваш [XAML](https://pastebin.com/i3mLHFbG) (добавил лишь закрывающий слеш у кнопки), как видите, все работает...

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, буду разбираться)